# Set Welcome Page - Office365 CSOM and C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I'm wanting to set the Welcome Page for my Sharepoint site using CSOM in C#.

Essentially what I'm doing is uploading my new welcome page (home.aspx) to either Site Pages or Pages and then I want to change the welcome page to match my newly uploaded page location.

I've looked around but a lot of what I've seen is either PowerShell or Server side code.

If someone can point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to set Welcome Page via SharePoint CSOM

```
public static void SetWelcomePage(Web web,string pageUrl)
{
    var ctx = web.Context;
    var rootFolder = web.RootFolder; 
    rootFolder.WelcomePage = pageUrl;
    rootFolder.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Usage

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    SetWelcomePage(ctx.Web, "SitePages/default.aspx");
}
```